# Show other view at application first launch

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have inherited some Windows Phone code that I must change. I need to show the user a tutorial about how to use the application when he first launches it. However, I cannot manage to change the current view...

Here is my code:

```
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new LoginViewModel();
        if (ApplicationFirstLaunched() == true)
        {
           NavigationManager.Current.Navigate(ApplicationView.DemoView);
        }
    }
```

The `ApplicationFirstLaunched` function works fine (I use `IsolatedStorageSettings` to store a boolean value), but the view never changes.. I thought that maybe the `Navigate` call was wrong so I created a button in my view and assigned its `Click` property to this function:

```
 private void demoBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    NavigationManager.Current.Navigate(ApplicationView.DemoView);
 }
```

When I click the button, the view changes and the tutorial pops up. What to do to show another view at first launch? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate in the OnNavigatedTo method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (ApplicationFirstLaunched() == true)
    {
       NavigationManager.Current.Navigate(ApplicationView.DemoView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that was easy.. Thank you!